# Gradle Copy task says no source

Tags: gradle

I have this Gradle script as deploy.gradle(Gradle 4.3.1):

```
defaultTasks 'echoProp'
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

task copyWar(type: Copy) {
    from "${source}"
    into "${target}"
    include '*.war'
}

task echoProp(dependsOn: copyWar) << {
    println "source dir: ${source}"
    println "target dir: ${target}"
    println "source = ${project.property('source')}"
    def currentJvm = org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.current()
    println currentJvm
}
```

This is the rough output:

```
                                        The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
    at deploy_13e4yjnom30svmprt2wccq4te.run(E:\environments\GRADLE_TEST\TEST\TESTDEPLOY\source\71\deploy.gradle:10)
    (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)
:copyWar NO-SOURCE
:echoProp
source dir: E:/environments/GRADLE_TEST/TEST/TESTDEPLOY/source/71
target dir: E:/environments/GRADLE_TEST/TEST/TESTDEPLOY/target
source = E:/environments/GRADLE_TEST/TEST/TESTDEPLOY/source/71
1.8.0_31 (Oracle Corporation 25.31-b07)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

This runs on a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine. I checked and there is a .war file in the defined source directory.

I can't figure out why it doesn't copy over the testApp.war file. I mean, the Source Directory are defined just fine by the other task, but why can't the copyWar task find these files?

---

Result of removing the << and running with the --info flag:

```
Initialized native services in: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\native
The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 5580). The daemon log file: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\daemon\4.3.1\daemon-5580.out.log
Starting 19th build in daemon [uptime: 1 hrs 14 mins 1.715 secs, performance: 98%, no major garbage collections]
Using 2 worker leases.
Creating new cache for fileHashes, path E:\environments\GRADLE_TEST\TEST\TESTDEPLOY\source\72\.gradle\4.3.1\fileHashes\fileHashes.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@6e59e113
Creating new cache for plugin-use-metadata, path C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\4.3.1\plugin-resolution\plugin-use-metadata.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@4092835c
Creating new cache for client-status, path C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\4.3.1\plugin-resolution\client-status.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@4092835c
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using settings file.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file 'E:\environments\GRADLE_TEST\TEST\TESTDEPLOY\source\72\deploy.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project '72']
Evaluating root project '72' using build file 'E:\environments\GRADLE_TEST\TEST\TESTDEPLOY\source\72\deploy.gradle'.
Compiling build file 'E:\environments\GRADLE_TEST\TEST\TESTDEPLOY\source\72\deploy.gradle' using SubsetScriptTransformer.
Compiling build file 'E:\environments\GRADLE_TEST\TEST\TESTDEPLOY\source\72\deploy.gradle' using BuildScriptTransformer.
source dir: file tree
target dir: E:/environments/GRADLE_TEST/TEST/TESTDEPLOY/target
source dir: E:/environments/GRADLE_TEST/TEST/TESTDEPLOY/source/72
target dir: E:/environments/GRADLE_TEST/TEST/TESTDEPLOY/target
source = E:/environments/GRADLE_TEST/TEST/TESTDEPLOY/source/72
1.8.0_31 (Oracle Corporation 25.31-b07)
All projects evaluated.
No tasks specified. Using project default tasks 'echoProp'
Selected primary task 'echoProp' from project :
Tasks to be executed: [task ':copyWar', task ':echoProp']
Creating new cache for resourceHashesCache, path E:\environments\GRADLE_TEST\TEST\TESTDEPLOY\source\72\.gradle\4.3.1\fileHashes\resourceHashesCache.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@6e59e113
Creating new cache for taskHistory, path E:\environments\GRADLE_TEST\TEST\TESTDEPLOY\source\72\.gradle\4.3.1\taskHistory\taskHistory.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@1e64a7a6
Creating new cache for outputFiles, path E:\environments\GRADLE_TEST\TEST\TESTDEPLOY\source\72\.gradle\buildOutputCleanup\outputFiles.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@4faa606d
:copyWar (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 15,5,main]) started.
:copyWar
Putting task artifact state for task ':copyWar' into context took 0.0 secs.
Skipping task ':copyWar' as it has no source files and no previous output files.
:copyWar NO-SOURCE
:copyWar (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 15,5,main]) completed. Took 0.002 secs.
:echoProp (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 15,5,main]) started.
:echoProp
Skipping task ':echoProp' as it has no actions.
:echoProp UP-TO-DATE
:echoProp (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 15,5,main]) completed. Took 0.004 secs.
```

also, the source and target variables from my Gradle.properties:

```
source=E\:/environments/GRADLE_TEST/TEST/TESTDEPLOY/source/72
target=E\:/environments/GRADLE_TEST/TEST/TESTDEPLOY/target
```

I'm completely new to Gradle, so I'm not sure what this all means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error is, that the `Copy` task has a property called `source`.
You give the `toString()` representation of this property (which is `file tree`) to the `from` method.
There of course no `WAR` files are found and thus the copy task has nothing to do.
Either rename your `source` property to something different, or use `project.source` to explicitly reference the `source` property of the project instead of the one from the task.

Besides that `into "${target}"` is identical to `into target` but is more performant. `source` and `target` are already strings, but you use them as placeholders which means the placeholder needs to be evaluated first which doesn't make too much sense.

Comment: "You give the toString() representation of this property (which is file tree) to the from method." What does that mean? What is the fix here?

Comment: As I described exactly what the problem is and how to fix it, I understand neither of your questions. What do you mean?

Answer (score 4):

Consider this `gradle.properties`:

```
srcDir=./dist
targetDir=./target
```

You can replace `dist` and `target` with your desired folders. Using `srcDir` means that we won't collide with properties of the `Copy` task.

Then, this `build.gradle`:

```
task copyWar(type: Copy) {
    from srcDir
    into targetDir
    include '*.war'
}
```

should work (it does for me).

Answer (score 1):

Check very carefully that you do not have directory or file names misspelled. Gradle doesn't tell you what it didn't recognize, it just says

```
Task :xxx NO-SOURCE
```

Comment: Gradle is a class of how not design a build system